# Accessing session from TWIG template

Tags: php, session, symfony, twig

I've searched a lot on the net how to access the global `$_SESSION` array from TWIG template and found this: `{{app.session.get('index')}}`, but when I'm calling it, it returns an empty string. I have a `$_SESSION['filter']['accounts']` and I'm getting this error when calling `{{app.session.get('filter').accounts}}`: `Item "accounts" for "" does not exist`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do NOT use $_SESSION in Symfony!

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`{{app.session}}` refers to the `Session` object and not the `$_SESSION` array. I don't think the `$_SESSION` array is accessible unless you explicitly pass it to every Twig template or if you do an extension that makes it available.

Symfony2 is object-oriented, so you should use the `Session` object to set session attributes and not rely on the array. The `Session` object will abstract this stuff away from you so it is easier to, say, store the session in a database because storing the session variable is hidden from you.

So, set your attribute in the session and retrieve the value in your twig template by using the `Session` object.

```
// In a controller
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->set('filter', array(
    'accounts' => 'value',
));

// In Twig
{% set filter = app.session.get('filter') %}
{% set account-filter = filter['accounts'] %}
```

Comment: thanks :) this helped me
P.S. you need to change your answer as this: `$session->set('filter', array( 'accounts' => 'value' ));`

Comment: What if sessions are stored in Memcached ?

Comment: @Sekai doesnt make a differnce i would say if you configured it correctly

Answer (score 35):

Setup twig

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment(...);    
$twig->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);
```

Then within your template access session values for example

```
$_SESSION['username'] in php file Will be equivalent to {{ session.username }} in your twig template
```

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: Yes, great answer.

Comment: Yes, great answer

Comment: Great answer because it works without Symphony. Not shown is how to do this within the view container, which is very similar. Where `$view` is the newly created Twig object, add the following to the container function (the same place you might add extensions).
`$view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);`

Comment: This code does not work in the latest Twig version. @user1279047

Comment: This solution does still work with Twig 3.x - the `Twig_Environment` class has been changed to just `Environment`.

Answer (score 22):

A simple trick is to define the $_SESSION array as a global variable. For that, edit the core.php file in the extension folder by adding this function :

```
public function getGlobals() {
    return array(
        'session'   => $_SESSION,
    ) ;
}
```

Then, you'll be able to acces any session variable as :

```
{{ session.username }}
```

if you want to access to

```
$_SESSION['username']
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the above, given that you can be using Twig without using Symfony.

Comment: Rather than edit core.php though follow the docs here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

Comment: @gazarsgo Both solutions are just great.

Answer (score 20):

The way to access a session variable in Twig is:

```
{{ app.session.get('name_variable') }}
```

Answer (score 7):

I found that the cleanest way to do this is to create a custom TwigExtension and override its `getGlobals()` method. Rather than using `$_SESSION`, it's also better to use Symfony's `Session` class since it handles automatically starting/stopping the session.

I've got the following extension in **/src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php**:

```
<?php    
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function getGlobals() {
        $session = new Session();
        return array(
            'session' => $session->all(),
        );
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

Then add this in **/app/config/services.yml**:

```yml
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then the session can be accessed from any view using:

```
{{ session.my_variable }}
```

Comment: This is nice. How can i set a session variable in twig using this solution??

Comment: @Ranhot, you shouldn't set session variables in twig views. That should be done in controllers or services.

Answer (score 1):

I found that in Grav CMS you could access session variables from twig like this:

```
{{ grav.session.variable }}
```