# Passing Session to TWIG template

Tags: php, twig, slim

i have a problem when i want to get `$_SESSION['session'];` in twig template using slim micro Framework.

this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>{{ title }} </title>
      </head>

     <body>
      <p> welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>                                                                                                                                       
         <p> {{ body }} </p>
       <a href="http://localhost/slim/public_html/logout">logout</a>
     </body>
  </html>
```

i can't get session username with that code.

any suggestion how to passing session to twig template?

Comment: Are you sure `$_SESSION['username']` has a value?

Comment: yes...i have teszt in my controller page i get my username value. but in twig template i can't get that value

Comment: It turns out that `$_SESSION` is unaccessible from the template. See [Accessing session from TWIG template](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8399389/1396314) for explanation and possible solutions.

Comment: i'm read that before, but i'm still not solve in my problem...any other suggestion? i'm using slim not symfony :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should register session as a twig global, so it becomes accessible in your templates.

```
//$twig is a \Twig_Environment instance
$twig->addGlobal("session", $_SESSION);
```

In your template:

```
{{ session.username }}
```

Comment: i think you right but not solve my problem.. ini my case i'm using slim and using twigview , how i can addGloball session in slim using twig template , this is library for twigview in slim https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Extras/blob/master/Views/TwigView.php

Comment: `getEnvironment()` of that class returns a `\Twig_Environment` instance. Example code: `$twigview->getEnvironment()->addGlobal("session", $_SESSION)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Slim and Twig as well.  My class:

```
class twigView extends Slim_View {
    public function render( $template) {
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->getTemplatesDirectory());
        $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
        $twig->addGlobal("session", $_SESSION);
                return $twig->render($template, $this->data);
    }
}
```

As you can see I've added `addGlobals`. Now it works as it should and I can use `{{session.user_id}}` and so.

A part of my index.php:

```
    require './lib/twigView_class.php';
    require_once './lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
    require './lib/Paris/idiorm.php';
    require './lib/Paris/paris.php';

    Twig_Autoloader::register();
```

I hope it will help you.

But is it safe to use 'global' in Twig ?

Answer (score 3):

This how I was able to achieve it with Slim Framework ver3

```php
$container['view'] = function ($container) {

    ...
    $view = new Twig($settings['view']['template_path'], $settings['view']['twig']);
    $view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);

    ...

    return $view;
};
```

And then access the session in the Twig template like

```html
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <img src="#" class="img-circle">&nbsp;{{ session.username }}<b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

in php file:

```
$app->get('/your_route_here', function() use ($app) {
$app->render('view_for_route.twig', array('session_username' => $_SESSION['username']) );});
```

in twig file:

```
<p> welcome {{ session_username }} </p>
```

You should pass the value from your PHP file into Twig via associative array.