# How to use Sessions in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, session, twig

what i need :

- i need to implement session in twig.
- i have implemented logic of code in php but d"nt have  any idea how to implement in twig.
- i have refer link [Accessing session from TWIG template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399389/accessing-session-from-twig-template).

here is code

```
              <?php
               session_start();
               if(isset($_SESSION["count"]))
               {
                 $accesses = $_SESSION["count"] + 1;
               }
               else
               {
               $accesses = 1;
               }
               $_SESSION["count"] = $accesses;
      ?>
   <html>
  <head>
 <title>Access counter</title>
 <script>
function callback()
{
   var page = "<?php echo $accesses; ?>";
               if (page >4)
               {
               alert("limit exceeded");         
               }
               else
               {
               alert("ok");                
               }
}
callback();
```

```
<p>You have visited this  <?php echo $accesses; ?> times today.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: well, please have a look at this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779219/passing-session-to-twig-template)

Comment: Are you using the Symfony 2 framework, or just the Twig component?

Comment: using  Symfony 2 framework

Answer (score 3):

You don't "implement sessions in Twig", period. You implement sessions in PHP code, and then pass any information that you may want to display in your HTML template to Twig to render. E.g.:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['count'] ... // do whatever you want here to count

$twig = new Twig_Environment(...);
echo $twig->render('my_template.twig', ['count' => $_SESSION['count']]);
```

This handles your session code, and then passes the session's count value to Twig. Inside your template, you can then output it:

```
<p>{{ count }}</p>
```

You can pass the entire `$_SESSION` array to Twig, so you have access to everything in it.

Comment: can you please guide how could i implement this in symphony custom functions

Comment: I have not used the entirety of Symfony yet, so no. If you need help specifically with that, ask a new question specifically for that.

Comment: can help  var page = "<?php echo $accesses; ?>"; when i want to call function count in javascript in twig .

Comment: `var page = {{ count }};` (Or `{{ accesses }}`, or whatever you name the value as when passing it to Twig.)

Comment: problem im facing is that there is no alert when web page is also reloded i have asked question in stackoveflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887673/how-to-use-session-in-symphony-using-custom-twig-extension

Comment: please tell why my alert is not working inn twig file where i have done wrong .

Comment: i have also tried {% block myJavascript %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("test");
</script>
{% endblock %}  but still not working