# How to Use Session in Symfony using Custom Twig Extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig

what i need

- i just want to implement session in symfony.

here is what i tried

- /src/Acme/bundlename/Twig

  Acmeextension.php

  ```
  public function getFunctions()
  {
    return array(
  'count'  => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'count'),
   );
   }   

  public function count()
  {
      session_start();
      if(isset($_SESSION["count"]))
      {
          $accesses = $_SESSION["count"] + 1;
      }
      else
      {
          $accesses = 1;
      }
      $_SESSION["count"] = $accesses;
      return $accesses;
  }
  ```

  here is the code of twig:

  ```
  function callback()
  {
      var page = {{ count}};
      if (page >4)
      {
          alert("limit exceeded");            
      }
      else
      {
        alert("ok");                 
      }
  }
  callback();
  ```

  ```
  calling in twig 
  {{ count }}
  ```

  - i just want  calculate pageviews.
  - i used script in twig so that i if there is page view are more then 4 then show alert message.
  - i have used symfony custom functions so that $SESSION in symfony.
  - i have implemented this code in core Php its working fine.
  - i have refer the link [Passing Session to TWIG template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779219/passing-session-to-twig-template).
  - custom Twig Extension http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Problem

- im not Gettig any alert in when i reload the page.
- please tell me where im wrong , any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: i have try debug code but still alert not working {% block myJavascript %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("test");
</script>
{% endblock %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to inject sessions outside of the scope meaning into your custom extension.

I would do this.

```
     //AppKernel +add
      protected function initializeContainer() {
          parent::initializeContainer();
          if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
              $this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
              $this->getContainer()->set('request', new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(), 'request');
          }
      }
```

Then in your services container

```
      <!-- Custom Twig Extensions -->
      <service id="yourid" class="yourclasspath">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        <tag name="twig.extension" />
    </service>
```

Then in your twig.php

```
     class Twig extends \Twig_extension {
         private $request;

         public function __construct(Container $container) {
              $this->request = $container->get('request');
         }

         public function getFunctions() {
           return array(
            'count'  => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'count'),
           );
         }    

         public function count() {
         $session = $this->request->getSession();

         if(session->has('count')) {
             $session->set('count') += 1;
         } else {
             $session->set('count') = 1;
         }

         return $session->get('count');
      }
   }
```

Then the same in your twig

Comment: syntax error unexpected ->(T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) ON THIS LINE if(session->has('count')) {

Comment: @Matthew: I think you are overcomplicating it with `service_container`. See my answer based on yours but a bit simplified ;)

Comment: @user3785613 that is what you get for copying and pasting i left out the $ sign lol

Comment: how to  solve alert issue  function callback()
{
    var page = {{ count}};
    if (page >4)
    {
        alert("limit exceeded");            
    }
    else
    {
      alert("ok");                 
    }
}
callback();
calling in twig 
{{ count }}

Comment: error PHP Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\Bundle\\Twig\\Acme Extension::__construct() must be an instance of Acme\Bundle\\Twig\\Acme Extension, none given, called

Comment: Whoa, slow down. You're going from one error to another without even paying attention. First thing, you **cannot** just use `{{ count }}` because `Twig` will think that is a `variable`. Instead, use `{{ count() }}`. As for the `AcmeExtension` (woot?!) please edit you question with changes you applied - only then we shall be able to help you...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some older version of `Twig`? Usage of `Twig_Function_Method` is deprecated.

If we ignore the subtle differences between older and new versions of `Twig` I would do it like this.

**Note: This is actually @Matthew's solution and but I took liberty to simplify it a bit :)**

<kbd>**Twig service definition**</kbd>

```
<!-- Custom Twig Extensions -->
<service id="yourid" class="yourclasspath">
    <argument type="service" id="session" />
    <tag name="twig.extension" />
</service>
```

<kbd>**Twig extension file**</kbd>

```
class Twig extends \Twig_extension {
     private $session;

     public function __construct(Session $session) {
         $this->session = $session
     }

     public function getFunctions() {
         return array(
             new \Twig_SimpleFunction('count', array($this, 'count') ),
         );
     }    

     public function count() {
         if($this->session->has('count')) {
             $this->session->set('count') += 1;
         } else {
             $this->session->set('count') = 1;
         }

         return $this->session->get('count');
     }
}
```

Comment: i have tried call count function using javascript but still there is the problem no alert works when page reload so where is the issue

Comment: Try it first **without** any JS. Just print: `<h1>THIS IS MY CONTER {{ count() }}`. Then we can trace back the error...

Comment: its now been fixed thank jperovic sol i have placed script code after body beacause of might script might collapse in page now its working fine