# Error when I use if with twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Symfony2 and twig and I have a problem when I try check if a var is null.

This is the code:

```
$name=null;

if($session->get('foo')) {

    $name=$session->get('foo');

}

return $this->render('AcmeIndexBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
```

And twig code:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% if name is defined %}
     {# do something #}
{% endif %}

{% block cuerpo %}

{# labels html}

{% endblock %}
```

the error is: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Node "1" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node".") in "AcmeIndexBundle:Default:index.html.twig".

Comment: This code is valid. I guess the error is somewhere else in your twig template. You have to share more code.

Comment: Hi Fred, its not working only when the code has a if

Answer (score 0):

you can use {% if name is not null %} but the code is valid

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: sry im newbie on stackoverflow , ty for explain. i would just try to help him

Answer (score 0):

where/how do you set foo in the session? 
I believe the issue could be foo is never set and you are passing a null value to the twig file you should handle the exception if foo is empty in the session
OR 
you may not be accessing the name value correctly.

alternatively sessions can be accessed directly using:

```
// In a controller
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->set('name', array(
    'foo' => 'value',
));

// In Twig
{% set name = app.session.get('name') %}
```

and then

```
{% if name is defined %}
     {# do something #}
{% endif %}
```

src:[Accessing session from TWIG template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399389/accessing-session-from-twig-template)

accessing variables/parameters in twig can get confusing as there are a million different ways to do it.

Comment: Hi, it either work, I've tried update twig but does not work.

Comment: then as Fred said it is most likely an issue with your twig file can you post it? i assume its an issue with your block or inheritance.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why, i have tried to update composer.phar but it is not working

Comment: Sorry, can't help much more without the code i need to see if/what you are extending

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your Twig code. The second hash (#) symbol is missing.

```
{# labels html}
```