# Session always null in Twig in Symfony 4 tests

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phpunit, symfony4

In upgrading Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 4.2 I have all unit test passing apart from functional tests on controllers where Twig is being rendered and using `app.session.get('my_session_variable')`.

Using the standard `app.session`, the `session` is always `null`.

I get the error:

```
Twig\Error\RuntimeError : Impossible to invoke a method ("get") on a null variable.
```

It appears the session is not getting set, even when I explicitly set a session in the test setup via:

`$this->client->getContainer()->get('session')->set('my_session_variable', 'help');`

The code is like the following:

Test class:

```
final class HomepageTest extends WebtestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->router = $this->client->getContainer()->get('router');
    }

    public function testMyPatience(): void
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('homepage');
        $this->client->request('GET', $url);

        $this->assertSame(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
final class Homepage extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/homepage", name="homepage", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('homepage.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Twig template:

```
{% if app.session.get('my_session_variable') != null %}
    <p>Session variable is set</p>
{% endif %}
```

config/test/framework.yaml:

```
framework:
  test: true
  session:
    storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing session from TWIG template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399389/accessing-session-from-twig-template)

Comment: @TomPaler Unfortunately not, I was trying to access the Session object in the standard way (`app.session`) as highlighted in the answer you've mentioned, but the issue was that does not work. Using `app.request.session` instead does however.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who has this issue, the solution was to use:

```
app.request.session.get('my_session_variable')
```

Instead of:

```
app.session.get('my_session_variable')
```