# Get session variable in twig template in shopware6

Tags: session, twig, shopware, shopware6

I have set a custom value in the session variable from the PHP class now I want to get the Session variable in the twig template in shopware6.
anyone can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing session from TWIG template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399389/accessing-session-from-twig-template)

Answer (score 4):

It's not considered best practice to access the session directly in the template. You should create a [subscriber](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events) to add variables to your template.

```php
class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            GenericPageLoadedEvent::class => 'onPageLoaded',
        ];
    }
    
    public function onPageLoaded(GenericPageLoadedEvent $event): void
    {
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();

        $event->getPage()->assign(['myVariable' => $session->get('someSessionKey')]);
    }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
{{ page.myVariable }}
```

For the sake of completion: You can also access the session object in the template directly.

```
{{ app.session.get('someSessionKey') }}
```

I'd still recommend going the extra mile with a subscriber to do some sanity checks though.

Comment: `sanity checks`?

Comment: `getSession` may throw `SessionNotFoundException`. It's not likely to happen at that point, but you never know. Hence a sanity check. Better safe than sorry.